# My 2 forms are closed when i click the button that is supposed to close only one of them

Tags: vb.net, winforms

So i have a WindowsForm Application in Vb that contains 2 forms : FirstSreen and SecondScreen

I have a button on the FirstScreen and I want that when I click that button, it makes the SecondScreen appear and close the FirstScreen so that only the SecondScreen will remain. So i wrote this code :

```
Public class FirstScreen 

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    SecondScreen.Show()
    Close()

  End Sub

End Class
```

But when i click the button, the SecondScreen shows up but disapears automatically with the FirstScreen. 
Do you know how to solve problem ? Help needed Thanks

Comment: If you close your startup form then your application terminates. You can Hide instead of Close

Comment: You should use explicit form instances.  Those default form instances are something only VB allows and sets you up for all sorts of problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple fix to this problem:

Your problem is caused by Visual Studio setting `Shutdown mode` to when the startup form closes:

[image]

You can change this to `When last form closes` instead:

[image]

You can find these in the settings application tab of your project. Below is an example of where to find it:

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you could say where/how to access these settings

Comment: oops sorry, I meant to when taking the screenshots. I'll update now

Comment: @Tony Stark If my answer has helped you, please upvote and accept, otherwise, please tell us if the problem persists

Comment: @Tony Stark Thank you :)